# How to merge commit in Gerrit Code Review

Tags: git, merge, commit, gerrit

I'm newbie to gerrit: http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/
I installed it with git on my local Mac. It's done.

I make some test action:

- register 2 accounts, the **first** accounts grant the "Administrators" privilege, the **second** account grant the "Registered Users"
- create new project
- I use the **second** account to push an commit to master branch for review. Add the **first** as reviewer
- Review is OK. How to merge this commit to main branch? Any solution by web UI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

Pay attention to 3 categories on Admin/Project/Access:

- CodeReview
- Verified
- Submit

I miss the 2 last categories, so, Gerrit don't show the submit button

Answer (score 8):

Once a commit has the maximum score in each category and no minimum scores in any category, it can be merged.  The default categories are Code Review (-2 to +2) and Verified (-1 to +1).  So to merge a commit, it must have a +2 Code Review and +1 Verified score, and no -2 Code Review or -1 Verified scores.

A user with 'Submit' privileges will see the 'Submit Patch Set n' button next to the 'Review' button.  Click it to merge the commit.

Answer (score 2):

The default permissions in Gerrit are not always what you might expect. In order for the first reviewer to be able to submit the review, you will have to give them (well, Administrators) permission to do a "+2" review score.

After you do this and the reviewer marks the commit as +2, then Gerrit will automatically merge the commit into the branch for which it was submitted.

Comment: Hi, I mark as +2. It only show the message "Looks good to me, approved". The code is not merged.

Comment: Did you press the "Submit" button after marking as +2? That is what tells Gerrit to perform the merge.

Comment: I don't see the button "Submit"

Comment: Can you give me the screenshot of it?

Comment: Not today, because my installation of Gerrit is at work, and I'm not. But here's the part of the documentation that shows the "Submit" permission: http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.2.0/access-control.html#category_SUBM

Comment: for whoever struggles with that, it seems like +2 review and +1 verify is necessary for a submit button to appear

Comment: When you say it "automatically merges," does it in fact *merge* as in creating a merge commit (with two parents)?  Or does it just *apply* the change as in creating one ordinary git commit (one parent) incorporating all the changes that have been reviewed?  ([This gist](https://gist.github.com/mbbx6spp/70fd2d6bf113b87c2719) describing gerrit seems to imply the latter.)

Comment: @Wildcard: What you're describing (as "applying" the change) is called a "fast-forward merge" in Git. It's still a merge, but without the two-parent merge commit.

Comment: @GregHewgill, got it.  But, if the master branch has been committed to between the time the change was made (created) and the time it was submitted (applied/merged), does Gerrit still apply it as a fast forward merge in the way that GitLab would call a "rebase, squash and fast forward"?  Or does it ever make a merge commit?  (Pointers to documentation welcome.)

Comment: @Wildcard: Gerrit can make merge commits too, depending on your situation, how you've set up Gerrit, and how you use branches in your project.